# VBA Selenium - Error Handler working only once in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In 1st run after error (after appearing PopUp) its going to `'#5 ErrorHandler:` which is good,

But in 2nd run after error (after appearing PopUp) its continuing to run from `'#2 Patient Name:`

I need to add more errorhandlersss to this script, like another one will come for `'#3  to #4` n so on,

but firstly I need errorhandler only for line `'#1 to #2`

Please suggest your suggestion as per this my requirement.

```
Sub Update_Status()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.START "Chrome"
bot.Get "https://www.ABCSite.in/"
 
    bot.FindElementById("username").SendKeys "USERID"
    bot.FindElementById("passwordd").SendKeys "PASSWORD"
    bot.FindElementById("loginbtn").Click
 
 

For i = 4 To x
 
'-------------------#1--------------------------
'SRF already entered or Wrong SRF
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
 
'Add Record from SRF Portal
    bot.FindElementById("home").Click
 
'SRF ID
    bot.FindElementById("srf_id").WaitDisplayed(True, 2000).SendKeys "Value"
    bot.FindElementById("btn").Click
    bot.Wait 1500
'----------<PopUp Appears>---------------
 
'-------------------#2--------------------------
 
'Patient Name
    bot.FindElementById("patient_name").SendKeys "Value"
'Patient ID
    bot.FindElementById("patient_id").SendKeys "Value"
 
'-------------------#3--------------------------
 
'#Passport Number
    bot.FindElementById("passport_number").WaitDisplayed(True).SendKeys "Value"
 
'-------------------#4--------------------------
 
    bot.FindElementById("btn").Click
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 41).Value = "Done"
 
nxtRow:
Next i
 
Exit Sub
 
'-------------------#5--------------------------
ErrorHandler:
            bot.Wait 1000
            bot.SwitchToAlert.Accept
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 41).Value = "Skipped"
            GoTo nxtRow
 
End Sub
```

I didn't understand that if its work in 1st run, why its not working in 2nd run ??
VBA Error: [image]

Comment: I think it's because you load page once before the loop, do something with the page and didn't reload page for the 2nd run

Comment: Can you please edit it for me, because i dont understand.

Comment: Can you describe more about the website you working with? After `bot.FindElementById("btn").Click` , is this page auto refresh or be redirected to another page?

Comment: mate it's a form filling webpage, where I fill patient details for my LAB,
Process > Need to login first> Home Page appear > need to put Patient ID to redirect to its form  > then fill the form ............ if patient id doent exist / or already done> it shows pop that "its already done or not exist"

Comment: try add  a `bot.Navigate().Refresh()` right after `bot.FindElementById("btn").Click`